# How to re-run another query in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

I have a workbook with several queries forming data tables.
Lets say, [Data1] is a query forming a primary table, which is referenced from [Data2] query.
How can I force refresh [Data1] query when I run [Data2] query?

Also, is query dependence taken into account when I press "Data/Refresh All"?
 They all seem to refresh simultaneously, but I think in fact the do it one-after-another.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to **query** Data1 from Data2, there is no need to refresh. PQ understands that it needs some more data and refreshes Data1 (as query) automatically.

```
let
    Data2=Data1 //PQ refreshes _query_ named Data1
in
    Data2
```

But if you refer to **table** Data1 on Excel's sheet, you should refresh it manually, since this table is static.

```
let
    Data2=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data1"]}[Content] //PQ doesn't refresh _table_ named Data1
in
    Data2
```